# GGPlotly: downloadHandler giving empty plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am having some difficulties with `plotly`. I would like to be able to download `plotly` as pdf. However while adding to my code some x and y axis parameters (cause if i transfer `ggplot` to `plotly`, titles of x and y axis are cut)

This code is working to download pdf file:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)


shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(downloadButton('downloadplot',label='Download Plot')),
    plotlyOutput('plot1')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    testplot <- function(){

a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = interaction(cyl, carb, lex.order = T), y = mpg,fill = interaction(cyl, carb, lex.order = T))) + 
  geom_boxplot()

    }

    output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({testplot()})

    output$downloadplot <- downloadHandler(
      filename ="plot.pdf",
      content = function(file) {
        pdf(file, width=12, height=6.3)
        print(testplot())
        dev.off()
      })})
```

and addition of this code to fix the titles of the `ggplotly` fails:

```
a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = interaction(cyl, carb, lex.order = T), y = mpg,fill = interaction(cyl, carb, lex.order = T))) + 
  geom_boxplot()

p <- ggplotly(a + ylab(" ") + xlab(" ")) 
x <- list(
  title = "[x]"
)
y <- list(
  title = "[y]"
)
p %>% layout(xaxis = x, yaxis = y)}
```

gives an empty plot...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: But where exactly i should use `return(a)`..Than i need to use if statement for `downloadHandler`

Comment: If you have plotly user_name etc you can use `plotly_IMAGE` for it. or you need to use different function one for plotly and one for pdf ggplot

Comment: I do not have plotly user_name. The problem with `plotly` is that i cannot use **plotly download image button** in Internet Explorer, thats why the only solution is to add `downlaodHandler` which is going to give me pdf file

Comment: Are you tried to create different fucntion - one with plotly and one withh ggplot ( only for pdf)?

Comment: I haven't tried it because my original code is more complex (having quite few different types of plots)

Comment: maybe this could help https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/webshot/webshot.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my question. The solution is not elegant but it works!

So the trick is to set the x and y titles in `renderPlotly` and NOT in `testplot()` function.

However the x and y axis titles have to be additionally typed in `testplot()` function - cause this is going to be our output as pdf, and view of the plot is done with `plotly`.

Here is code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)


shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(downloadButton('downloadplot',label='Download Plot')),
    plotlyOutput('plot1')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    testplot <- function(){

      a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = interaction(cyl, carb, lex.order = T), y = mpg,fill = interaction(cyl, carb, lex.order = T))) + 
        geom_boxplot()

    }

    output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({

      p <- ggplotly(testplot() + ylab(" ") + xlab(" ")) 
      x <- list(
        title = "[x]"
      )
      y <- list(
        title = "[y]"
      )
      p %>% layout(xaxis = x, yaxis = y)})

    output$downloadplot <- downloadHandler(
      filename ="plot.pdf",
      content = function(file) {
        pdf(file, width=12, height=6.3)
        print(testplot())
        dev.off()
      })})
```